# iPhone --- 3DES Encryption returns "wrong" results?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encryption, 3des

I have some serious trouble with a CommonCrypto function. There are two existing applications for BlackBerry and Windows Mobile, both use Triple-DES encryption with ECB mode for data exchange. On either the encrypted results are the same.

Now I want to implent the 3DES encryption into our iPhone application, so I went straight for CommonCrypto:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-32207/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h

I get some results if I use CBC mode, but they do not correspond with the results of Java or C#. Anyway, I want to use ECB mode, but I don't get this working at all - there is a parameter error showing up...

This is my call for the ECB mode... I stripped it a little bit:

```
const void *vplainText;

plainTextBufferSize = [@"Hello World!" length];
bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);

plainText = (const void *) [@"Hello World!" UTF8String];
NSString *key = @"abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcd";

ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
     kCCAlgorithm3DES,
     kCCOptionECBMode,
     key,
     kCCKeySize3DES,
     nil, // iv, not used with ECB
     plainText,
     plainTextBufferSize,
     (void *)bufferPtr, // output
     bufferPtrSize,
     &movedBytes);
```

t is more or less the code from here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9017515
But as already mentioned, I get a parameter error each time...

When I use kCCOptionPKCS7Padding instead of kCCOptionECBMode and set the same initialization vector in C# and my iPhone code, the iPhone gives me different results. Is there a mistake by getting my output from the bufferPtr? Currently I get the encrypted stuff this way:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

It seems I almost tried every setting twice, different encodings and so on... where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the error message?

One of the best ways to troubleshoot this stuff, I've found, is to take known input, known key and known output ("[test vectors](http://www.google.com/search?q=triple+des+test+vectors)") and compare the bytes of the expected output with the observed output.

What you're doing here is probably not a good way to test the output:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

How do you know the encrypted binary data can be interpreted with the `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` encoding?

Instead, compare the bytes directly (via `[myData description]` or the like) or translate the output with hexadecimal or [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395968/cocoa-base-64-implementation-for-rest-auth/1396039#1396039) encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I managed to get it up and running with kCCOptionPKCS7Padding (read: CBC mode). It seems the encoding of the output was the problem.

I'll use this instead the ECB mode, but I'm still curious why I get the error - the function just returns a kCCParamError if kCCOptionECBMode is used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that kCCOptionECBMode alone is not enough.  You also need padding (since it is a block cypher).  If you pass both (i.e. kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode ) it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but for reference, I think that your key should not be passed in as an NSString. The key should instead be converted from hexadecimal to a byte array. This [hexToBytes NSString extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes) should provide what you need by doing the following:

```
[[key hexToBytes] bytes]
```

The key should also be twice as long as the one given (48 characters of hex, i.e. 24 bytes).