# iPhone SHA-1 encoding different results from Rails?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, encoding

Ruby code:

```
  a = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', 'secret', 'example')
```

and then:

```
 Base64.encode64(a).chomp
```

yields

```
 aMp6Zw1+hHVMmwWXoFp/Aaipc20=
```

iPhone:

```
+ (NSData *)hmac:(NSString *)input withKey:(NSString *)key {
    const char *cstrInput = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cstrKey = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstrInput length:input.length];

    unsigned char chmac[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cstrKey, strlen(cstrKey), data, [data length], &chmac);

    NSData *hmacData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:chmac length:sizeof(chmac)];
    return [hmacData autorelease];
}
```

And

```
[XICrypto hmac:@"example" withKey:@"secret"];
NSLog(@"HMACData: %@",[HMACData description]);
NSString *HMACEncodedString = [HMACData base64Encoding];
```

(Where base64Encoding method is from Alex Reynold's answer on [Cocoa Base 64 Implementation for REST Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395968/cocoa-base-64-implementation-for-rest-auth))

Results yield

```
Qm+ManmzmtfhpOzFdf8UHW43L5o=
```

So these methods are not performing the same operations, why?

EDIT: digest and key were backwards in the Rails call. Fixed that, yet the result is still different from the iPhone's call.

Comment: Have you looked here? I'm not sure you're using the correct function to perform your SHA-1 encryption - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468268/objective-c-sha1.

Comment: CCHmac is supposed to be the 1 function call for init update and final. I am looking into the issue and string encoding is making the biggest difference.

Comment: @Perception, I don't see the option for a secret key in that post.
@Joe, Do you see any issue with the encoding?

Comment: Had the rails call key & data backwards as per the docs: HMAC.digest(digest, key, data) → aString

Updated post with correct param order & new result aMp6Zw1+hHVMmwWXoFp/Aaipc20=

Comment: @quanumpotato - your right, you need to be able to pass in the key so the other post doesn't help much, if any. @Joe might be onto something with the character encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I see your comment after I figured out that part on my own :), your rails call is backwards, your next issue is encoding. When ever you want the correct length of bytes when using string encoding use `lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`.

```
+ (NSData *)hmac:(NSString *)input withKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSStringEncoding encoding = NSASCIIStringEncoding;
    const char *cstrInput = [input cStringUsingEncoding:encoding];
    NSUInteger inputLength = [input lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:encoding];
    const char *cstrKey = [key cStringUsingEncoding:encoding];
    NSUInteger keyLength = [key lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:encoding];

    unsigned char chmac[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cstrKey, keyLength, cstrInput, inputLength, &chmac);

    return [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:chmac length:sizeof(chmac)] autorelease];
}
```

I logged the contents of the data and get `68ca7a67 0d7e8475 4c9b0597 a05a7f01 a8a9736d` and if you paste that into the hex field of [this translator](http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/) you will get `aMp6Zw1+hHVMmwWXoFp/Aaipc20=` in the base64 field.

Comment: Your orignal method could be fixed also by using strlen(cstrInput) when creating the data instead of input.length to make it a quick fix.