# Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix) equivalent in Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c, algorithm

I have this function in Java:

```
private String hexStringToByteString(String s) {

    String r = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2)
        r += (char) Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 2), 16);   

    return r;
}
```

and must implement this in Objective C, because I am developing an app and have to do some encryptions. The problem is I don't know how to make the Integer.parseInt part, passing a String and a radix int to the function. Some help will be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString r = @""; 
r = [r stringByAppendingString: [ [s substringWithRange:NSRangeMake(i, i + 2)] intValue]];
```

Or:

```
NSMutableString r = @""; 
[r appendingString: [ [s substringWithRange:NSRangeMake(i, i + 2)] intValue]];
```

It's just that I believe there are better ways of achieving the same. Can you provide a bit more about what `s` contains and what you are about to achieve? e.g. when this is done just to get rid of spaces, then the following would do - even without the for loop.

```
NSMutableString r = [NSMutableString stringWithString:s];
[r replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
```

Edit in response to your comment. 
But be warned. Use this as a starting point only. I never did that myself before. There may be better solutions around and it may contain minor mistakes.

```
- (NSString) hexStringToByteString(NSString s) {

  NSMutableData d = [NSData dataWithLength: [s length] / 2];

  NSUInteger v; 

  for (int i = 0, i < [s length], i+=2) {
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[s substringWithRange:NSRangeMake(i, i + 2)]];

    [scanner scanHexInt:&v];

    [d appendBytes:&v length:1];
  }

  NSData r = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  return r;
}
```

You may opt for a different encoding of course.

Comment: I am just trying to pass a hexadecimal string to a decimal string.

Comment: Apologies I overlooked the radix parameter for some reasons. Considering that my answer is not correct.

Comment: See the mended answer.