# How to put a Hex string to byte array in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring

I want to put the Hex String to array

```
NSString *hex = @"1a2b3c";  //3 bytes
uint8_t array[3];
memcpy(array, [hex cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ,3);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&array length:3];
NSLog(@"%@" , data);
```

OUTPUT becomes ASCII: <316132>

If I want output to be <1A2B3C>, how should I do it ?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes) what you need?