# Convert string to byte array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string variable in iOS and I would like to convert that to a character array and then to a hex bytes like 0xD6, 0xD6 etc.

It will be great if there is a library in Objective-C that I can use for this

Comment: What encoding do you want the bytes? And have you looked at the documentation for `NSString`? There are plenty of methods available depending on what you are actually trying to get. Please [edit] your question with a clear example of what you have and what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be answer is here:

**string to chars:**

```
NSString *s = @"Some string";
const char *c = [s UTF8String];
```

**chars to hex:**

```
- (NSData *)dataFromHexString {
    const char *chars = [self UTF8String];
    int i = 0, len = self.length;

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:len / 2];
    char byteChars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    unsigned long wholeByte;

    while (i < len) {
        byteChars[0] = chars[i++];
        byteChars[1] = chars[i++];
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, NULL, 16);
        [data appendBytes:&wholeByte length:1];
    }

    return data;
}
```

reference:[NSString (hex) to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes)

Answer (score 2):

swift 4

```
 string to byte:

 let strChar = "A" 
 let data1 = [UInt8](self.strChar.utf8)
```

Comment: Please add some description rather than just giving a block of code.

Comment: Correction to the above: `let data1 = [UInt8](strChar.utf8)`

Comment: @ScottMcMillin Thanks for suggest.