# Convert NSString to unsigned char type array in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert NSString to unsigned char type array, I have searched many things but have not found a way to do it, can someone suggest me?
ex: input : 16
output: 0x01, 0x06

The input has only the characters of hexa code.
I am newly for this objective C and cocoa application so please help on this. Thanks!

Comment: What is input:`abc` supposed to be?

Comment: sorry for not write clearly, I want use hexa code, input only number and "A,B,C,D,E,F". A = 0x10, B =0x11...

Comment: Hex are two bytes. Do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [example] to your question. See also [ask].

Comment: @vadian yes, It seems that is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`const char* array = [string UTF8String];`

This will give you a pointer to the null-terminated array with UTF8 representation of the string.

Answer (score -1):

Loop the characters in the string and then you can do what you want with them, e.g. print or calc or whatever. I'm sure there are samples of this lying around.

```
// s is the string ...
for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < s.length; i ++ )
{
  unichar c = [s characterAtIndex:i];

  // ... do something with c
}
```

Comment: Well ... this approach is overkill for converting to hex but made sense earlier.